How to show suggestion when input double quotes in monaco-editor?
When input double quotes in monaco-editor, it doesn't show suggestions like vscode: .
use this playground to input double quotes - playground
I want that the editor can show suggestion like vscode after input double quotes. How to solve this problem in monaco-editor?
